# "System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data" error in VS Development Server but not in IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 in Windows 7 64bit dev box. My asp.net works fine when using IIS on the box but when I switch to using Visual Studio Development Server, I get an exception "System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data" in this line (in Application_AuthenticateRequest event in global.asax.cs):

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

Why does this fail when using the internal web server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try deleting your cookies after you switch servers. Both servers have their own configuration and probably their own [decryption key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) with which the forms authentication cookie is encrypted and decrypted. Thus, if you still have the cookie encrypted by IIS, then switch the project to use the built-in development server and hit the site, that server can't decrypt the cookie.

You can prevent this issue if you put the decryption key in your web.config:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="..." />
```

Comment: I am having similar issue - Kindly help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653227/how-to-decrypt-the-cookie-inside-custom-url-rewrite-provider

Answer (score 0):

There is another cause of this error.  If your MachineKey entry in the Web.config file ends with

```
xmlns=""
```

Then you will also suffer this error.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Michiel van Oosterhout's method but it did not work. however, then I added:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms protection="Encryption" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/>
</authentication>
```

Now it works.