# How to decrypt the cookie inside custom URL rewrite provider?

Tags: iis, cookies, url-rewriting

I have a website where I created a custom cookie and I am trying to read the cookie value inside my Custom Rewrite Provider running in IIS

Question in short: How to decrypt the cookie inside custom URL rewrite provider?

**Below is the code for creating custom cookie**

```
     FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
           1,                                    
           model.Email,                          
           DateTime.Now,                          
           DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),          
           true,                         
           "deepak",                             
           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie fCookie = new HttpCookie("customCookie", encryptedTicket);
        fCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        fCookie.Path = "/";
        Response.Cookies.Add(fCookie);
```

**Below code is to read the cookie value inside my Custom Rewrite Provider running in IIS**

```
   public class ParseUserNameProvider : IRewriteProvider, IProviderDescriptor
   {
    public IEnumerable<SettingDescriptor> GetSettings()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Initialize(IDictionary<string, string> settings, IRewriteContext rewriteContext)
    {}

    public string Rewrite(string value)
    {
        string[] val = value.Split('=');
        string name = "";
        if (val != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(val[1]);
            if(authTicket!=null)
            {
                name = authTicket.Name;
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Error raised as shown below**
[image]

**Rewrite Settings in IIS - InBound**

**Redirect URL**

http://1x2.xx.1x8.x8:1111/Report/Report?name={ParseUserNameProvider:{C:0}}

**Conditions**

[image]

I learned this from : http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Note: This post is NOT duplicate of [Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900415/custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module) because I am getting different error.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any other Cookies with that domain they'll be included as part of val[1] in one long string. I had considerable difficulty making IIS reliably pass through just one cookie so I pulled though all the cookies into val[1] string and then split that into an array of all the cookie values then just selected the one I needed. If in doubt get your provider to out put the val[1] string as a customer error so you can see what it's seeing.

```
        throw new Exception(val[1]);
```

Once you can see what's actually being received you work out how you need to split it.

Comment: HowD, there are no multiple cookies, i throwed exception as you suggested and saw it is proper encrypted value. let me know how to decrypt it?

Comment: Hi Deepak, suspect because they are different applications then the Forms Authentication method is using different encryption keys so you get the wrong result. Try taking a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

Comment: Exactly, but my second application is console application and it do not have web or app.configurations to add MachineKey. even I tried to add machine key as suggested in the link you have provided but did not work. I am happy that you understood my requirement. if I crack it, i will update the post.

Comment: Have considered creating your own encryption utility then you can hard code the key directly into the code.

Comment: Yes tried it, it works fine but I trust Microsoft encryption more than my encryption logic due to time limit. Yes as you rightly said it will be the last option for me. Also curious to know why it's not working technically. Hope it's valid question and it get's up vote so that more people can look it and help me.